# kryptonDockingManager save file and load file not working after restart app

Tags: winforms, krypton-toolkit, krypton

i am using https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton repo 
i am using vs 2015 community
win 10

i am saving config file then close app then load here all is blank

This is my code

```
        //load dock
        private void loadDockToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                kryptonDockingManager.LoadConfigFromFile(@"C:\Users\SWT\Desktop\setting.ss");
            }
            catch (Exception rr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(rr.Message);
            }
        }

        //save dock
        private void saveDockToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                kryptonDockingManager.SaveConfigToFile (@"C:\Users\SWT\Desktop\setting.ss");
            }
            catch (Exception rr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(rr.Message);
            }
        }
```